# bash script for creating a text file with all files with specific ending

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, regular-expression

I know this is a bloody beginner question. But maybe someone has a short answer on this one.
In my folder I have several files that end on `.SAFE`. There are files with different endings though aswell... I would like to create a `.txt` file in which each line is one of those files.
After that I'd like to run a programm that uses this `.txt` file as input. And all that I'd like to do in one bash-script. More or less like:

```
programm.sh
####
1. get all files with .SAFE-ending
2. make a file called files.txt
3. run <some_program>
```

My folder looks like this

```
files.txt
S2A_MSIL1C_20200418T101031_N0209_R022_T32UPB_20200418T122607.SAFE
S2A_MSIL1C_20200418T101031_N0209_R022_T32UQB_20200418T122607.SAFE
S2A_MSIL1C_20200421T102021_N0209_R065_T32UPB_20200421T111956.SAFE
S2A_MSIL1C_20200421T102021_N0209_R065_T32UPB_20200421T122440.SAFE
S2A_MSIL1C_20200421T102021_N0209_R065_T32UQB_20200421T111956.SAFE
S2A_MSIL1C_20200421T102021_N0209_R065_T32UQB_20200421T122440.SAFE
S2A_MSIL1C_20200424T103021_N0209_R108_T32UPB_20200424T124310.SAFE
S2A_MSIL1C_20200428T101031_N0209_R022_T32UPB_20200428T111417.SAFE
S2A_MSIL1C_20200428T101031_N0209_R022_T32UQB_20200428T111417.SAFE
S2A_MSIL2A_20200418T101031_N9999_R022_T32UPB_20200430T165258.SAFE
```

And the `files.txt` looks like this: (just that I created it with python)

```
2A_MSIL1C_20200418T101031_N0209_R022_T32UPB_20200418T122607.SAFE
S2A_MSIL1C_20200421T102021_N0209_R065_T32UPB_20200421T122440.SAFE
S2B_MSIL1C_20200426T101549_N0209_R065_T32UPB_20200426T131809.SAFE
S2A_MSIL1C_20200421T102021_N0209_R065_T32UQB_20200421T111956.SAFE
S2A_MSIL1C_20200421T102021_N0209_R065_T32UPB_20200421T111956.SAFE
S2B_MSIL1C_20200423T100549_N0209_R022_T32UQB_20200423T135558.SAFE
S2B_MSIL1C_20200423T100549_N0209_R022_T32UPB_20200423T135558.SAFE
S2A_MSIL1C_20200428T101031_N0209_R022_T32UQB_20200428T111417.SAFE
S2B_MSIL1C_20200426T101549_N0209_R065_T32UQB_20200426T131809.SAFE
S2A_MSIL1C_20200421T102021_N0209_R065_T32UQB_20200421T122440.SAFE
S2A_MSIL1C_20200424T103021_N0209_R108_T32UPB_20200424T124310.SAFE
S2B_MSIL1C_20200419T102549_N0209_R108_T32UPB_20200419T124956.SAFE
S2A_MSIL1C_20200428T101031_N0209_R022_T32UPB_20200428T111417.SAFE
S2A_MSIL1C_20200418T101031_N0209_R022_T32UQB_20200418T122607.SAFE
```

Afterwards I run `parallel -j4 <some_programm> :::: files.txt` on the command line.

This all works, but I'd like to make all this in one `bash script`. One of the reasons is, that I'd like to learn some shell-scripting.

I'm thankful for any advice:)

Comment: So what should the script do exactly? Why don't you just run `parallel -j4 <some_programm> ::: *SAFE`?

Comment: yes I did this. I just wanted to know how to do it in bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `parallel` and run a command on all the files ending in `.SAFE`, all you need is:

```
parallel -j4 <some_program> ::: *.SAFE
```

Or, if your file names can contain `\n`, use `-0`:

```
parallel -j4 -0 <some_program> ::: *.SAFE
```

Saving filenames in a file is rarely a good approach. For one thing, it will break if the filenames can contain `\n` (newline) characters unless you make the file null-separated. You usually want to use a glob instead. Still, here are a few ways of getting filenames into a file:

1. Simple, but can't deal with newlines in file names:

   ```
   printf '%s\n' *.SAFE > filenames.txt
   ```
2. More complex, but can deal with arbitrary file names:

   ```
   find . -type f -name '*.SAFE' -print0 > filenames
   ```

   That creates a NULL-separated file, so you need a tool that can handle such input. `parallel` can do it with `-0`:

   ```
   parallel -0 -j4 <some_program> :::: filenames
   ```

So with this approach, your script could be:

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -type f -name '*.SAFE' -print0 > filenames
parallel -0 -j4 <some_program> :::: filenames
```

But, if your file names don't have spaces or newlines or any other strangeness, just run `parallel -j4 -0 <some_program> ::: *.SAFE` and be done with it.

Comment: `parallel -j4 <some_program> ::: *.SAFE` deals correctly with any strangeness except \n and \0 (in particular space, ', ", and * are absolutely fine). `parallel -j4 -0 <some_program> ::: *.SAFE` deals correctly with any strangeness except \0.

Comment: @OleTange ah, thanks, I thought `:::` could deal with newlines without the `-0` since it was passed a glob. Answer edited.

Comment: Yeah, it is one of those corner cases that may be changed in future versions, because it is not what you would expect.